# How to find a usable executable file in bash

Tags: bash

I have written this little script to find executables that are passed as arguments e.g.

```
./testexec du ls md
```

How do I get the script to not output commands that are not found - e.g. not to display error output for "md" command ??

```
  #!/bin/sh

    for filename in "$@"
    do
    which $filename
    done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using bash, you should use the builtin "type" rather than the external utility "which". The type command will return a non-zero exit status if the command is not found, which makes it easy to use with a conditional.

```
for filename in "$@"; do
   if type -P "$filename" >/dev/null; then
       echo "found in PATH: $filename"
   fi
done
```

Comment: @frodo: You can also capture the location of the executable like this: `for filename in "$@"; do if dir=$(type -P "$filename"); then echo "found in PATH: $dir"; fi; done`

Answer (score 3):

Just redirect the error message (coming from `stderr`) into `/dev/null`:

```
which $filename 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you eduffy - I take it this means the "2" means "standard error " so any errors will be sent to /dev/null ? - apologies for the basic newbie question

Comment: Yes, "2" is stderr. Processes in *NIX start with 3 file descriptors:
`0 - stdin
1 - stdout
2 - stderr
`