# How to programmatically detect available utilities in Linux or OS X

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out if a command exists on POSIX system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762631/find-out-if-a-command-exists-on-posix-system)
>   [How to find a usable executable file in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401863/how-to-find-a-usable-executable-file-in-bash)

On the command line I'd type (e.g.) `type vimdiff` (or `which vimdiff` if `type` is not available on the machine).  But in a script, what is the most reliable way to check for a utility and then take some action depending on its availability.

The purpose at hand, if it helps to know, is I'm writing a function, `thediff`, which I can install on local and remote machines of various operating system and various flavors of OS, and let it pass arguments off to p4merge if it's available (for OS X and Windows/Cygwin environments), and if not then try `vimdiff` and use that if it's available, and if not then default to `diff` with my preferred options (e.g. `--side-by-side --suppress-common-lines --ignore-space-change`').

Since `which` is notoriously unreliable in the form of feedback it gives, I'm not sure if I can count on `$?` being `1` if the utility in question is not installed.  But on the other hand, I'm not sure I can rely on `type` being installed at all.

It seems kludgey, but what about just trying the first utility, and if `$?` is non-zero then trying the next, etc.

How is this generally handled?

***UPDATE***:

Although I did tag this with 'bash', that was only to get the attention of people following the bash tag, since they'd be likely to know an answer.   I did *not* mean to imply that I only ever use bash, or that I can assume bash will be present on all systems I use.  In fact I've had to work on systems where grumpy sysadmins made it difficult to use anything but the Korn shell.  And (whenever available) I use zsh instead of bash.   So this is *not* an exact duplicate of [How to find a usable executable file in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401863/how-to-find-a-usable-executable-file-in-bash) since that requires bash.  So the questions are different.  Further, *I explicitly stated that I've had to use systems where `type` is not available*.  All the closers apparently overlooked that fact.

This question might legitimately be a duplicate of the other question, *if* all the systems I mentioned are in fact POSIX compliant.  I don't know whether they are.

Comment: `which` returns 1 to `$?` if the file is not found.  See `man which` for details.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that fact in my question, but since `which` is notoriously unreliable, and generally frowned upon, can I trust that *all* versions across *all* OSs and all distros will behave that way?

Comment: If you require cross `POSIX` compatibility you can use `command -v` which is part of `POSIX` and returns >0 when the command isn't found.

Comment: I'm not sure whether all Linux distros, OS X, and Cygwin can all be assumed to be POSIX compliant.  Can they?

Comment: See my answer here, which works anywhere bash is available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401863/how-to-find-a-usable-executable-file-in-bash/8402148#8402148

Comment: @jordanm: can I trust that even ancient versions of bash have `type`?  I don't remember where, but I know I've run into situations where it wasn't available, but I might have been using `zsh` at the time...

Comment: @iconoclast it existed in bash version 1.14.7. I can't find changelogs that go back further than that to find when it was actually introduced. Most likely the early 1990s.